# Linked Lists in C without malloc functions

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, malloc

How can use this program without using malloc? If I use `temp.next=&newtemp` the program work without error? I have to learn how can avoid malloc.

```
    for(int ;;){
    printf("Fusni N(numrin e qyteteve): "); scanf("%d", &N);
    if(N<13 || N>100) {printf("Futet N gabim\t( 13 < N < 100)\n\n");continue;}
M=1;
while(1){
p = q = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    p->id_qyteti = 1;

    for (i = 2; i <= N; ++i) {
        p->pas = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        p = p->pas;
        p->id_qyteti = i;
    }

    p->pas = q;
 printf("M=%d, Zonat ku nderpritet rryma:\n", M);

for (count = N; count > 1; --count) {
 printf("%d ",p->pas->id_qyteti);   p->pas = p->pas->pas;
if(count==2)printf("\n\n");
      for (i = 0; i < M - 1; ++i) p = p->pas;
}
if(p->id_qyteti==13)

 {
printf("13.Tirana ngelet e fundit\n");
   printf("M-ja minimale: %d\n", M);
   break;

 }
else M++;

}}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's either UB or your program is actually valid if you don't return the address of block scope automatic variables. But I really don't know, this code is such a great amount of unreadable mess.

Comment: how can i reorganize the code ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use it with arrays, but the problem is that you are going to have a limited capacity.
For example you can have a `struct yourstruct[500];` and a integer that shows where is next free struct, si intead of mallocing you will do something like `mynode->next = &yourstruct[i++]` of course you must have  a better control to know where a free struct is.

Comment: How can i use it with arrays?

Comment: first i have to do this : node* new = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node)); but program say that i have an error , undeclared function New.